# Change iFrame size on button click

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, iframe

I'd like to implement an iFrame preview that changes size to mobile or tablet dimension when the corresponding buttons are clicked. I already got a solution that used to work but strangely enough does not work anymore when I'm implementing it on my WordPress site.
Since I'm quite new to programming I'm having trouble figuring out what's the problem here.

Thank you for your help!

```
<div class="resize-grid resize-margin-small-bottom">
    <div class="resize-width-1-1">
      <button class="resize-button2 resize-button-primary resize-margin-small-right"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i></button>
      <span class="resize-text-danger"></span>
    
      <button class="resize-button resize-button-primary resize-margin-small-right"><i class="fa fa-tablet"></i></button>
      <span class="resize-text-danger"></span>
    
      <button class="resize-button1 resize-button-primary resize-margin-small-right"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i></button>
      <span class="resize-text-danger"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
 
  <iframe width="1920" height="1080" src="https://example.com" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

 <script>
$('.resize-button').on('click', function() {
  $('iframe').animate({
    width: 768,
    height: 1024,
  });
});

$('.resize-button1').on('click', function() {
  $('iframe').animate({
    width: 360,
    height:  640});
});

$('.resize-button2').on('click', function() {
  $('iframe').animate({
    width: 1920,
    height:  1080});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the quotation just solve the issue.

```js
$('.resize-button').on('click', function() {
  $('iframe').animate({
    width: "768px",
    height: "1024px",
  });
});

$('.resize-button1').on('click', function() {
  $('iframe').animate({
    width: "360px",
    height:  "640px"});
});

$('.resize-button2').on('click', function() {
  $('iframe').animate({
    width: "1920px",
    height:  "1080px"});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="resize-grid resize-margin-small-bottom">
    <div class="resize-width-1-1">
      <button class="resize-button2 resize-button-primary resize-margin-small-right"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i></button>
      <span class="resize-text-danger"></span>
    
      <button class="resize-button resize-button-primary resize-margin-small-right"><i class="fa fa-tablet"></i></button>
      <span class="resize-text-danger"></span>
    
      <button class="resize-button1 resize-button-primary resize-margin-small-right"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i></button>
      <span class="resize-text-danger"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
 
  <iframe width="1920" height="1080" src="https://example.com" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But that didn't do the trick for me. When I insert the code into my Wordpress site it works like one time and then the buttons don't work anymore.